# Saving contact with notification in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-contacts

i am creating an APP in Android in which i send my details like phone #,email ,Facebook Address to other person via bluetooth in a text File.I want that whenever the 2nd person receive my text file ,It should prompt the other User that `Whether he want to save my details as a Contact`.My question is ,is there any built in function that can serve the purpose,as in QR-Reader after reading it asks for saving.
Anyone who can help me with this
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure but there is Contact push Notification for Android.used year ago..Google it for answer

Comment: Its more likely to prompt them about the bluetooth connection I think.

Comment: @CodeDroid no not a prompt for bluetooth connection,Prompt for saving in the contact...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send the info inside the Text file and then use [Android Contact Provide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.html) to save it in your contacts.You can use the Gesture interface to detect the tap and use Dialog box for YES/No (User Permission).